# Adapting grid with expanders to available height

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a 'pile' of expanders on top of each other, which can be opened/closed independently.

All but one have a fixed height (when expanded). The other has a `MinHeight`, but I would like it to stretch to fill the remaining available height. If the combined heights of the expanders is greater than the available height, then scrollbars appear.

I've got that far using a `Grid`, with one expander per grid, and the row `Height` set to `*` for the stretching expander, and `Auto` for the others.

This works fine except in one case: if the stretchy expander is collapsed, and the combined height of the other expanders is *less* than the available height, then the stretching expander fills the remaining space anyway, just with it's content collapsed so I get a big blob of background colour.

I've also tried a StackPanel, or nested Grids, but haven't managed to resolve that problem without creating others.

Any ideas?

(Paste this into a Window)

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="23"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Expander IsExpanded="False" Grid.Row="0" Header="Fixed">
            <Border Background="Red" Height="200" />
        </Expander>
        <Expander IsExpanded="False" Grid.Row="1" Header="Stretchy">
            <Border Background="Blue" />
        </Expander>
        <Expander IsExpanded="False" Grid.Row="2" Header="Fixed">
            <Border Background="Green" Height="300" />
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Could you insert your xaml? It's clear more or less, but i wanna see it :)

Comment: @sac1 Your wish is my command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Expander takes by default all available space. It does this by setting `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch`.

To solve your problem set `VerticalAlignment` to `Top`. Then the Expander takes only the space it needs.

The XAML would look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander Grid.Row="0" Background="Green">
        <Button Height="50">test</Button>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Grid.Row="1" Background="Red">
        <Button Height="50">test</Button>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Grid.Row="2" Background="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button Height="50">test</Button>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:**

You should bind the `Height` of the second row to `IsExpanded` of the stretchy expander. If it is expanded, set it to `*`, if not, set it to `auto`. You can do this by using a `ValueConverter`.

**EDIT 2:**

As promised the markup and the value converter that solve your problem:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=Stretchy, Path=IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" MinHeight="23" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Expander IsExpanded="False" Grid.Row="0" Header="Fixed">
            <Border Background="Red" Height="200" />
        </Expander>
        <Expander x:Name="Stretchy" IsExpanded="False" Grid.Row="1" Header="Stretchy" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="100">
            <Border Background="Blue" />
        </Expander>
        <Expander IsExpanded="False" Grid.Row="2" Header="Fixed">
            <Border Background="Green" Height="300" />
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

ValueConverter:

```
public class BoolToHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool? v = value as bool?;
        if (v == false)
            return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
        else
            return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I posted my sample code, which you might want to try. Your fix does help to not give me the big blob of blue background, but I still have problem with the stretchy expander not collapsing properly.

Comment: That is not a problem of the Expander, its a problem of the Grid. If you mark the middle one with `Height=*`, then it takes the rest of the space, regardless of its contents. In you case I suggest changing the Height to `auto`

Comment: @Benjol okay, I think I understand your problem now. Just to clarify: If the combined Height of all expanders are less than the window height, the Stretchy expander should still use up all the remaining space, even if it is more than it needs?

Comment: @Benjol now the answer should do exactly what you need ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to fill out your answer. I tweaked it ever so slightly to get it to work for me.

Comment: If you only need this in one place and don't want a converter, you could use RowDefinition.Style containing a DataTrigger on RowDefinition.Height